# Need an explanation of the given solution

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A bored student walks down a hall that contains a row of closed lockers, numbered $1$ to $1024$. He opens the locker numbered 1, and then alternates between skipping and opening each locker thereafter. When he reaches the end of the hall, the student turns around and starts back. He opens the first closed locker he encounters, and then alternates between skipping and opening each closed locker thereafter. The student continues wandering back and forth in this manner until every locker is open. What is the number of the last locker he opens?

Now the solution given using the recursion is

We can also solve this with recursion. Let $L_n$ be the last locker he opens given that he started with $2^n$ lockers. Let there be $2^n$ lockers. After he first reaches the end of the hallway, there are $2^{n-1}$ lockers remaining. There is a correspondence between these unopened lockers and if he began with $2^{n-1}$ lockers. The locker $y$ (if he started with $2^{n-1}$ lockers) corresponds to the locker $2^n+2-2y$ (if he started with $2^n$ lockers). It follows that $L_{n} = 2^{n} +2 -2L_{n-1}$ as they are corresponding lockers. We can compute $L_1=2$ and use the recursion to find $L_{10}=\boxed{342}$

There was an another solution but I am more interested in learning the recursion because I am a bit weak at it. In this solution what did the solution mean to say when it is talking about the locker $y$ . It says that there is some sort of correspondence between the unopened lockers which is the part I don't get.  Can somebody please explain what it means to say?

Comment: Just consider the first cycle.  Consider a "new" labelling system, that labelling all *closed* lockers in reverse order.  For example, you will have $1024$th locker be labelled as new-$1$, $1022$th locker is new-$2$.  You will obtain the recurrence.

Comment: @ElfHog Thanks for your explanation